# Modular exponentiations with two moduli?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can someone explain the following modular exponentiation statement step by step? The statement is:

Suppose $p,q$ are primes and $q~|~p-1$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}_q$ and $k^{-1}$ is computed mod $q$. Then, for any given $a \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$(a^{k\cdot k^{-1}} \mod p) \mod q$$

is equal to $$(a \mod p) \mod q$$

I had a rough intuition but a careful step by step explanation will be very helpful.

Comment: What does "mod $p$ mod $q$" mean?

Comment: @EricWofsey just updated the notation.

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting the notation, this isn't true.  Take $p=7$, $q=3$, $k=2$, and $a=3$.  Then $k^{-1}$ mod $q$ is $2$, and $3^{2\cdot 2}$ is $4$ mod $7$ which is $1$ mod $3$, whereas $3$ is $3$ mod $7$ which is $0$ mod $3$.